# Gnome Shell shows black screen with moving cursor

Tags: gnome, backup, laptop, gnome-shell-extension

I have Ubuntu 22.04 and was tuning Gnome with exstensions. At one point the screen just completely froze, I waited 5 min and decided to power off my laptop (by pressing the power button). Now everytime I login to my main account (lacinquette) (display manager/login screen works perfecly normal) I get black screen with only cursor I can move (on Xorg, on Wayland cursor appears but not moves).

I have another account (non root "guest") which I logged in to see if it is also broke - no, Gnome shell is working just fine under that user.

Luckily, using the standard Ubuntu app (which comes by default) I scheduled regular backups for my main user (they are stored in `/home/lacinquette/laptop/`) - maybe it could help somehow.

For some reason I don't have access to tty (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>/<kbd>F1</kbd>), but I managed to login to main account using grub recovery boot.

I tried to recover my /home/lacinquette folder using:

```
sudo duplicity --no-encryption file:///home/lacinquette/laptop/ /home/lacinquette --force
```

But nothing changed, screen is still black. Tried to restore backup again - it gives me `Errno 17 File already exists` - the result is nothing.

Having access to command line, what can I do from now?

**Edit**: I'm using Lenovo laptop with AMD gpu and cpu.

Comment: what extensions did you install/enable?

Comment: @Esther Toggle VPN was the last one. There were like 10-15 extensions, including Clipboard, OpenWeather, one for system monitoring, some for top bar and dock customization and etc. Also had problems with OpenWeather, Transparent dock (or smth like that) sometime before the freeze.

Comment: try disabling all extensions using the command from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029376/how-do-i-enable-and-disable-gnome-extensions-from-the-command-line), likely one of them (or some interaction between two or more) is causing the issue.

Comment: @Esther didn't work. Nothing changed, unfortunately.

Comment: After each extension you added to the system you used it for a few days before the next so you would know there were no issues?

Comment: @David I didn't do that. I installed bunch of extensions at the same time and was using them simultaneously. But next time I think I will test it before adding to main user...