# Can't activate Gnome extensions

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I've got a few extensions installed in Ubuntu 23.10 but I cannot activate them. Neither from the Gnome Extensions app nor from https://extensions.gnome.org/local/. I toggle an extension from off to on and nothing happens. I refresh the page and the toggle is back to off. Nothing happens after restarting Gnome or the computer. The extensions are not controversial (like Open Weather or Cap Locks). Not sure why the extensions stay off.

Comment: There may be a problem related to your current user. Please, try with another (preferably newly created) user and see if you have the same problem there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable and disable GNOME extensions from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029376/how-do-i-enable-and-disable-gnome-extensions-from-the-command-line)