# System crash since last update to Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS February 2024

Tags: gnome, updates, 22.04, crash

Since the last update, GNOME has crashed the whole system. It hangs if I move the mouse and click on the desktop on any item.
It's possible to start a shell using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.
Figured out that the system works after running the statement below:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-shell
```

After that, the system works until the next reboot.
Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Do you maybe have any extensions that might cause this? I would try and disable all extensions, and go from there..

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/1029376/1004020 but it's caused by an extension